# CSS blur filter not working in edge when transform property is set

Tags: css, filter, microsoft-edge

As the title suggests, the blur filter does not work in Edge when the transform property is set. The fiddle below demonstrates this.

https://jsfiddle.net/wkjvwgyy/1/

```css
#content-background {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;

    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

    background: url("https://i.imgur.com/qfGEt3o.jpg") no-repeat top center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: blur(5px) brightness(60%);
}
```

```html
<div id="content-background" style="transform: scale(1.03)"></div>
```

On removing the transform property, the blur works fine. It also works correctly in Chrome and Firefox. Is this a bug in Edge?

Both [transforms](https://caniuse.com/#search=transform) and [filters](https://caniuse.com/#search=filter) should be supported on Edge 15, which I'm running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, this is a bug in Edge.

This should work:

```
#content-background {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("https://i.imgur.com/qfGEt3o.jpg") no-repeat top center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    transform: scale(1.03)
}

#content-background::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url("https://i.imgur.com/qfGEt3o.jpg") no-repeat top center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: blur(5px) brightness(60%);
}
```

Comment: This works, but on Edge there still remains an unblurred outline as seen at https://i.imgur.com/0MjIfDu.png. I suppose one alternate solution would be to apply the filter on the image beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

> The filter property is not supported in Internet Explorer, Edge 12, or Safari 5.1 and earlier.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_filter_blur

In other words, it only works in Edge 13 or later.

Comment: I'm running Edge 15. Also, the blur filter works correctly on its own. The issue only occurs when the transform property is also set.